# Why do Java's GtkLookAndFeel Popups have no border?

Tags: java, swing, gtk, look-and-feel

I have an already written Java Swing app (so no switching UI frameworks) that I would like to look at least decent using the GTKLookAndFeel.  I've already accounted for things like font and component size differences across LookAndFeels, but one thing I can't figure out is why my popup menus have no borders at all.  It appears they are using Synth borders which don't look GTK native.  I would like to be able to support Metal, Windows, and GTK, but these popups look terrible.  Is this a bug? What's a nice (non hacky) way to fix this without affecting the other LookAndFeels' borders which look fine?

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion GTK LaF is broken by design. It does *not* honor the programmers UI settings (font color borders background etc) for seemingly random JCOmponents. This is because it gets its settings from a .gtkrc file, not setXXX(...) calls. I'd stick with Metal for Linux and 'native' for windows.

Response:

> The GTK+ look and feel can be
>   customized by way of resource files.
>   Swing's GTK+ look and feel uses the
>   following algorithm to locate the
>   resource files:
>
> 1. If the system property swing.gtkthemefile exists, parse it
>      and stop, for example: java
>      -Dswing.gtkthemefile=/tmp/customTheme -jar SwingSet2.jar.
> 2. If the file user.home/.gtkrc-2.0 exists, parse it and continue.
> 3. Determine the user selected theme name (THEMENAME) by way of the
>      desktop property gnome.net/ThemeName
>      which is determined using XSETTINGS.
>      If this property is null, use Default
>      as THEMENAME.
>           1. If the file user.home/.themes/THEMENAME/gtk-2.0/gtkrc
>      exists parse it and stop.
>           2. If the system property swing.gtkthemedir exists and the file
>      swing.gtkthemedir/THEMENAME/gtk-2.0/gtkrc
>      exists, parse it and stop.
>           3. If the system property swing.gtkthemedir doesn't exist and
>      the file
>      /usr/share/themes/THEMENAME/gtk-2.0/gtkrc
>      exists, parse it and stop.
>           4. Lastly if swing.gtkthemedir is defined parse
>      swing.gtkthemedir/THEMENAME/gtk/gtkrc,
>      otherwise parse
>      /usr/share/themes/THEMENAME/gtk/gtkrc.
>
> One way GTK+ can be customized is by
>   way of a theme engine. A handful of
>   engines exist. In 1.4.2, Swing
>   supports theme files for Default,
>   pixmap, and bluecurve engines. We are
>   investigating ways to open up the API
>   to allow for the creation of
>   additional GTK engines. Visit
>   http://www.themes.org for examples.
>   - http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/guide/swing/1.4/Post1.4.html

My guess is that java is taking its theme from another rc file OR the current border options aren't supported.

Comment: But if it's following a .gtkrc, the popups should have a border and shadow, since all of the other native apps do.

Answer (score 2):

I know the response is belated, but if anyone sees this question on google (like I did) then I find that this solution is better than nothing:

```
    if (UIManager.getLookAndFeel().getClass().getName().equals("com.sun.java.swing.plaf.gtk.GTKLookAndFeel"))
        aPopupMenu.setBorder(BorderFactory.createMatteBorder(1, 1, 1, 1, Color.gray));
```

It doesn't seem to work for menus added to popup menus (even if you call the function on them), but it does show the border on the primary menu.

Answer (score 1):

There are incompatible rc-files.

Unfortunately the http://www.ailis.de/~k/ blog is closed.

**Ubuntu/Gnome Shell:** e.g. `/usr/share/themes/Adwaita/gtk-2.0/gtkrc`

```
style "menu" { 
xthickness = 1 
ythickness = 1 ... 
} 
... style "separator_menu_item" { 
xthickness = 1 
ythickness = 1 
... }
```

Update 11/30/2015: For **Ubuntu/Unity** refer http://blog.hani-ibrahim.de/en/ubuntus-swing-gtk-laf.html => Global menu, native fonts.

On **Linux Mint** there are the `menus.rc` files in the Mint-themes in `/usr/share/themes/[mint-theme]/gtk-2.0/style`

In section *style “menu”* change:

```
xthickness = 0
ythickness = 0
text[ACTIVE] = @base_color
```

to:

```
xthickness = 1
ythickness = 1
text[ACTIVE] = @fg_color
```

In section *style “menu-item-separator”* change the entry:

```
ythickness = 0
```

to:

```
ythickness = 1
```

I wrote a [bash-script](http://blog.hani-ibrahim.de/en/swing-menus-gtk-laf.html) for Mint which does the job automatically. It fixes all 3 problems:

- Missing menu border.
- Wrong font color of activated checkbox and radiobutton menu items (the font has the same color as the background and appears invisible).
- No menu separators.

Comment: If the bash-script URL does not work (GDPR issues) use my Github account at https://github.com/haniibrahim/swing-menu-corr.